# read json and show the dynamic value onmouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Requirement is to read Json object and the value should be shown on mouse over a tooltip.
Please find the code in http://jsfiddle.net/8WKTj/49/

Below is the JSON code:

jsonDataFile.js

```
{ 
  "Column1": "This represents transID",
  "Column2": "This represents Spread percentage",
  "Column3": :" Column3 title description";
}
```

javascript:

```
$(function()
        {
           $(".question").each(function(index)
            {
              $.getJSON("js/jsonDataFile.js",function(result){
                  $.each(result, function(i, field){
                      alert(" i: " + i +" ,"+ field); //prints i: column1 ,This represents transID 
                                  //i: column2 , This represents Spread percentage
                      $(this).prop('title', result[index]);
                  });
              });

            });
        });
```

When i mouse over on column1, tooltip should display the message "This represents transID" . Similarly when mouse overon column2 , tooltip should display "This represents Spread percentage"...I have tried reading json file and show message on tooltip as above but output is not as expected. It's not showing anything onmouse over. Please suggest.

Comment: Can you add the full path to you json data file to the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

1) Why you are reading SINGLE(!) static JSON from network for EACH question? It's far mor correct to reverse logic and BIND QUESTIONS FROM JSON, and not BIND JSON TO QUESTIONS, especially because getJSON is async by nature instead of $(..).each

2) Never use alert() - it locks main thread of JS and is real crasher for debugging - use console.log  or console.debug for printing debug information (!) - to see such messages U should launch embeded browser console or something like FireBug

3) Split logic to readable functions like applyQuestion(element, resultItem){}

4) Cache arrays in variables

So here is pseudocode with normal logic (should be like this)

```
$(function(){
    var applyQuestion = function(e, result){/* 
    here logic to setup element with item
    and as a part of it - you can setup "mouseoverevent" with some things from result
    */};
    var questionElements = $(".question");
    $.getJSON(url, function(result){
        questionElements.each(
            function(e){ applyQuestion(e,result);}
        )
    });

})();
```

So it's much clear and can be translated to human language "on the start, load json file and as it loaded store it's data into target elements by standard binding funcion"